# Can more than one thermodynamic process occur at the same time?

Tags: thermodynamics

Thermodynamic processes I know about are, Isothermal, Adiabatic, Isochoric and Isobaric (if you know any other, please mention).

Is it possible that any 2 or more of these four processes occur together in the same closed system?

Comment: It is also possible that some chemical reaction happens during any thermodynamic process.

Answer (score 2):

There 4 are just 4 special cases of an abstract path a TD system  changes its state via a particular TD process.

In special cases, a TD system can have 1 or a combination of the above attributes, if there is enough degrees of freedom for the process to occur with multiple constant values of state variables.

But a general TD process may have neither of these  4 attributes. I.e. a TD process may be neither isothermal nor adiabatic nor isobaric nor isochoric.

E.g. chemical reaction can occur both isothermally+isobarically, or isothermally+isochorically.

Or, it may be neither isothermal as temperature changes, nor isobaric as pressure changes, nor isochoric as volume changes, nor adiabatic, as there is heat flow to surrounding space.